# Review task bug on iPad

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

When using Stack Overflow and I am editing a post whilst doing review tasks on my iPad, (and only if the edit is during a review) the bar that gives you guidance for reviewing the item moves all over the screen and, no matter where I scroll, usually ends up covering the text that I am trying to edit. I can scroll down and view what I am typing in the preview screen, but to move the cursor position, I need to hide the keyboard. The bar then moves to the top of the screen, and I can house my position in the post, starting the whole saga over again.

Is this a known bug? Are there any plans to fix it? I find it really annoying; it hampers my efforts to improve the content and the community.

Comment: As a data point, it's not just on an iPad.  The same thing happens on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1...

Comment: Nexus 7/Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

On the next build we will no longer dock the review bar for tablet devices.